# Unable to attach two reference inputs to a transaction with Plutus Emulator

Tags: plutus, minting, offchain

I have written a script that will fail unless it receives both `oref1` and `oref2` as reference inputs. I have the following emulator code:

```
let rule = mempty
                     <> C.mustReferenceOutput oref1
                     <> C.mustReferenceOutput oref2
                     <> C.mustMintValue val 
                     <> (C.mustBeSignedBy ppkh)
tx <- mkTxConstraints @Void (plutusV2MintingPolicy policy) rule
submitTxConfirmed tx
```

The script fails saying that `oref1` is not a reference input. But if I comment out `C.mustReferenceOutput oref2` then the script fails saying it has not received `oref2` as a reference input. It seems I can attach `oref1` or `oref2` as a reference input, but not both.

On the testnet, this issue does not occur, so it isn't a problem with the script. Is it not possible with the Plutus emulator to attach more than one reference input to a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

It does work with the emulator. Here's a test that demonstrates this being validated on-chain.

https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/9bb44b617212fa195701f0c4a59d6f0e60b7764d/plutus-contract/test/Spec/Contract/Tx/Constraints/MustReferenceOutput.hs#L195-L196